# MVC DataReader Timeout Error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this problem with error timeout, always when it suppose to get data from database it bounce error. I am trying to retrieve video from database with this code:

**Repository.cs**

```
public List<videoTble> Video()
{
        var model = new List<videoTble>();

        string ConStr = "Data Source="";Connect Timeout=60";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
        {
            string str = "SELECT * FROM videoTbles";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
            SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rd.Read())
            {
                var v = new videoTble();
                v.Name = rd["Name"].ToString();
                v.Data = (byte[])rd["Data"];
                v.ContentType = rd["ContentType"].ToString();
                v.ArtistName = rd["ArtistName"].ToString();
                v.Expirydate = (DateTime)rd["Expirydate"];

                model.Add(v);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return model;
    }
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
        Repository res = new Repository();

        ViewBag.Video = res.Video();
        return View();        
}
```

**Model.cs**

```
public partial class videoTble
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expirydate { get; set; }
}
```

[The timeout Error I got, when i run application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkYLf.png)

Comment: Do you have a lot of data in videoTbles?

Comment: Try removing this from your code and see if it makes any difference.  "cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;"

Comment: Removing cmd.CommandTimeout = 60 will leave the default value of 30. It will timeout even faster then. if you set cmd.CommandTimeout = 0, it will wait forever.

Comment: Try optimizing your sql query. If that doesn't help then try adding a `httpRuntime` entry in `web.config` under `system.web` with values for the below and check if it helps. `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="1200" />`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are storing your video as raw data in your database. I highly advise against this. Store the video files on your file system, and store the paths to the video files in your database.